# Jenkins fails to start after a restart with "hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException"

Tags: jenkins

A week ago I had to restart our Jenkins, I did so via "jenkins url"/restart At first it was stuck on "please wait while Jenkins is restarting" for like...1.5 days, so I figured something was wrong.

I troubleshooted and restarted the service (daemon) itself as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17344061/please-wait-while-jenkins-is-restarting-waiting-long) post suggested. After the manual restart the jenkins page spat out this error

```
    hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to read history for build2
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:239)
Caused by: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to read history for build2
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:269)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:44)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:969)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:850)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:85)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:227)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to read history for build2
    at hudson.plugins.jobConfigHistory.FileHistoryDao.getRevisions(FileHistoryDao.java:748)
    at hudson.plugins.jobConfigHistory.FileHistoryDao.hasDuplicateHistory(FileHistoryDao.java:804)
    at hudson.plugins.jobConfigHistory.ComputerHistoryListener.onChange(ComputerHistoryListener.java:94)
    at hudson.plugins.jobConfigHistory.ComputerHistoryListener.onConfigurationChange(ComputerHistoryListener.java:52)
    at hudson.model.AbstractCIBase.updateComputerList(AbstractCIBase.java:209)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.updateComputerList(Jenkins.java:1293)
    at jenkins.model.Nodes$7.run(Nodes.java:304)
    at hudson.model.Queue._withLock(Queue.java:1312)
    at hudson.model.Queue.withLock(Queue.java:1189)
    at jenkins.model.Nodes.load(Nodes.java:295)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$17.run(Jenkins.java:2739)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$8.runTask(Jenkins.java:958)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to read /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/config-history/nodes/build2/2018-06-13_11-41-13/history.xml
    at hudson.XmlFile.read(XmlFile.java:144)
    at hudson.plugins.jobConfigHistory.FileHistoryDao.getRevisions(FileHistoryDao.java:746)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException:  : only 1.0 is supported as <?xml version not '1.1' (position: START_DOCUMENT seen <?xml version=\'1.1\'... @1:19) 
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.XppReader.pullNextEvent(XppReader.java:124)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.readRealEvent(AbstractPullReader.java:148)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.readEvent(AbstractPullReader.java:141)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.move(AbstractPullReader.java:118)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.moveDown(AbstractPullReader.java:103)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.XppReader.<init>(XppReader.java:63)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractXppDriver.createReader(AbstractXppDriver.java:54)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractXppDriver.createReader(AbstractXppDriver.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1053)
    at hudson.XmlFile.read(XmlFile.java:142)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: only 1.0 is supported as <?xml version not '1.1' (position: START_DOCUMENT seen <?xml version=\'1.1\'... @1:19) 
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.parseXmlDeclWithVersion(MXParser.java:2608)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.parseXmlDecl(MXParser.java:2592)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.parsePI(MXParser.java:2466)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.parseProlog(MXParser.java:1447)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1395)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1093)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.XppReader.pullNextEvent(XppReader.java:109)
    ... 28 more
```

I guess it has to do with a slave not restarting correctly but I ain't sure, does anyone have any guesses what my next steps should be? I have already removed all the plugins for jenkins to no avail. I have also tried to start the jenkins.war file through Java, but it just says that putty can't be started and aborts. The jenkins is running on a MAC

Sorry if the solution is super obvious, I haven't got that much experience with Jenkins. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So I feel stupid now, but I solved it. I took another look at the error and found `Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to read /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/config-history/nodes/build2/2018-06-13_11-41-13/history.xml
    at hudson.XmlFile.read(XmlFile.java:144)`

I went to the file and the found that the first row said `<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>`. I also noticed that the error message said

```
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: only 1.0 is supported as <?xml version not '1.1' (position: START_DOCUMENT seen <?xml version=\'1.1\'... @1:19) 
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.parseXmlDeclWithVersion(MXParser.java:2608)
```

I changed the `<?xml version='1.1>` to `<?xml version='1.0>`, saved the file and restarted jenkins using

```
sudo launchctl stop org.jenkins-ci
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
```